# How can I make google maps follow the new marker position?

Tags: javascript

I have Longitude and Latitude variables being updated with new positions constantly and setting a new position for the marker on the map with them. When the marker starts to move off screen, I want the map to be able to follow it at all times. How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
 <script>
 function initialize() {
 var Longitude = //coordinates from server
 var Latitude = //coordinates from server
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude);
 marker.setPosition(latlng);

 });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
 </script>
```

Comment: add center-map on that location

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Assuming that you have something like this
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'));
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(mylat,mylong));
```

Also, google this topic, there are tons of articles and examples available. Also search [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) for list of methods.
Check [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_events.asp) as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setCenter` method of the [Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) class. You should use it when you first initialize your map, and every time the marker changes position.

```
<script>
 var map; // you need to keep a reference to the map object in the global scope so you can call setCenter on it after initialization
 function initialize() {
     // initialize your map
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

     var Longitude = //coordinates from server
     var Latitude = //coordinates from server
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude,Longitude);
     marker.setPosition(latlng);

     map.setCenter(latlng); // center your map on the marker location

     });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```